# setting the linewidth in gnuplot when the color is given by a 4th axis

Tags: gnuplot

To plot 3D data xyz with the color given by a 4th variable I can use the command

```
splot   'au' u 1:2:3:4 linecolor palette with lines
```

where au is a file containing 4 columns of data.
If I try to adjust the width of the line to make it easier to see it gives the error below. What it the correct way to set the line width when taking colour from a palate given by a 4th axis

```
gnuplot> splot   'au' u 1:2:3:6 linecolor palette with lines lw 2
                                                             ^
     duplicated or contradicting arguments in plot options
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line properties must all come next to each other in the plot command; you can't stick something else (in this case `with lines`) in the middle. Use either

```
splot 'au' u 1:2:3:6 linecolor palette lw 2 with lines
```

or

```
splot 'au' u 1:2:3:6 with lines linecolor palette lw 2
```